# Android live update?

Tags: android, json, live, live-update

I'm creating a android game which communicates with a web server using JSON. 
When someone starts a new game versus another user I want that user to get a 
immediate notification. So far I've made the notifications and they work, 
but it only checks when I log in to the game, how do I create a live update
that checks with a, perhaps, one minute interval even if the game is closed?

---

c2dm.php

```
<?

function googleAuthenticate($username, $password, $source="Company-AppName-Version", $service="ac2dm") {


    session_start();
    if( isset($_SESSION['google_auth_id']) && $_SESSION['google_auth_id'] != null)
        return $_SESSION['google_auth_id'];

    // get an authorization token
    $ch = curl_init();
    if(!ch){
        return false;
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
    $post_fields = "accountType=" . urlencode('HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE')
        . "&Email=" . urlencode($username)
        . "&Passwd=" . urlencode($password)
        . "&source=" . urlencode($source)
        . "&service=" . urlencode($service);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // for debugging the request
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // for debugging the request

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); //for debugging the request
    //var_dump($response);

    curl_close($ch);

    if (strpos($response, '200 OK') === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // find the auth code
    preg_match("/(Auth=)([\w|-]+)/", $response, $matches);

    if (!$matches[2]) {
        return false;
    }

    $_SESSION['google_auth_id'] = $matches[2];
}


function sendMessageToPhone($authCode, $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText) {

    $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authCode);
    $data = array(
        'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
        'collapse_key' => $msgType,
        'data.message' => $messageText //TODO Add more params with just simple data instead           
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
    if ($headers)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
?>
```

C2DMRegistrationReceiver

```
public class C2DMRegistrationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.w("C2DM", "Registration Receiver called");
    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
        Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID");
        final String registrationId = intent
                .getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

        Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId
                + ", error = " + error);
        // TODO Send this to my application server
    }
}

public void sendRegistrationIdToServer(String deviceId, String registrationId) {

    Log.d("C2DM", "Sending registration ID to my application server");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("myserverpage");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        // Get the deviceID
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", deviceId));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationid", registrationId));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("HttpResponse", line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

C2DMMessageReceiver

```
public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.w("C2DM", "Message Receiver called");
    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
        Log.w("C2DM", "Received message");
        final String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
        Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: payload = " + payload);
        // Send this to my application server
    }
}
}

public void register(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    intent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    intent.putExtra("sender", "app-name@gmail.com");
    startService(intent);
}
```

Now if I start a game against someone, I have a class that sends the information to the server. Then how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish what you want by implementing a `Service`.  However, making an HTTP request to get the status every minute will be a drain on the battery.  I would suggest looking into [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) in order to send a push notification to the client.

Comment: You know a good tutorial or something? Because I need to know how to do both on the server side and the device side. Also, I program the server in php.

Comment: A good one (which appears to be down at the moment) is here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#c2dm_sendmessage.  The server side is shown on Java, so you'll have to port it to PHP.  Until the site is back up, you can view the cached version here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zrU0h--nBpIJ:www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us